# Cross-resource query with app() expression from the portal, “The following application isn’t available anymore”

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to use the cross-resource query (with 2 subscriptions) from the an Application-Insights resource's, Logs(Analytics) blade in the Azure portal?

I've managed to use the full qualified name for the same app I'm using!

i.e. using 
`app("/subscriptions/sub1/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/microsoft.insights/components/apptelemetry1").requests` in apptelemetry1 returns the same result as the query `requests`. But trying to use a similar query for an app in another subscription doesn't work (I've double checked the resources names many times).

I've Tried using  the all of the options listed in [app-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/app-expression),
[cross-workspace-query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query).
(Resource name, Qualified Name, ID, Azure Resource ID).

The only response I'm getting is: `"The following application isn’t available anymore"`.

Comment: In the other application insights named "apptelemetry1" -> logs(analytics), can you successfully run the same query: app("/subscriptions/sub1/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/microsoft.insights/components/apptelemetry1").requests

Comment: @IvanYang This wasn't possible as well.
Looks like an auth issue, since I can get to any other telemetry I tried this way (from different apps).

Comment: Yes, if the above is not possible, check your auth:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use this query `app("/subscriptions/sub1/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/microsoft.insights/components/apptelemetry1").requests` in the application insights instance **apptelemetry1** itself, there must be some problem with the instance **apptelemetry1**.

You can check if you have the [read access to the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/app-expression#notes).

And if it's still cannot after assign `read access`, you can [submit a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) where you can get professional help from Microsoft.